# ReferanceError ao executar script

Tags: javascript, json

O Código abaixo muda o innerHTML de uma DIV e quando executo a função `item.Footer();` o console do javascript me diz "ReferanceError 'item is not defined?"

```js
 (function() {var item ={
 Name: "site-info"
 Html: "Powered by <a target='_blank' href='https://www.twitter.com/FRNathan13'></a>"
 Footer: function(){
  document.getElementById(item.Name).innerHTML=item.Html;
 }
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="site-info"><button onclick="item.Footer();">MUDAR DIV!</button></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás a defenir esse objeto dentro de uma função. Isso faz com que  a variável/objeto não esteja acessível no escopo global em que o HTML corre. Para resolveres isso podes usar `window.item = {}` mas nesse caso perde a razão de usar `(function(){...})();`...

#### jsFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0fc52ms/

O melhor seria adicionares um oscultador de evento dentro dessa função, em vez de teres `onclick` no HTML. Algo parecido com:

```
(function () {
    var item = {
        Name: "site-info",
        Html: "Powered by <a target='_blank' href='https://www.twitter.com/FRNathan13'></a>",
        Footer: function () {
            this.parentNode.innerHTML = item.Html;
        }
    }
    document.querySelector('#' + item.Name + ' button').addEventListener('click', item.Footer);
})();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0fc52ms/1/